# Flask Python and css variable

Tags: python, css, variables, random, flask

I currently trying to build an online random color generator with python and flask. I have created my function which generate a random hex color code and I struggle to pass it into the css background color.

```
def random_color():
def r():
    return random.randint(0, 255)
return ('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(), r(), r()))
```

BR

Edouard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to genrate the random hex values as you did (or the way I did, by just just slightly improving code with [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)) in your code example and pass that value into the template context, where you would put it somewhere in `<style>` tag. This will render template and substitute dynamic value every time you visit the page.

```
# app.py
import random

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    hex = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*random.sample(range(256), 3))
    return render_template('index.html', hex=hex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

# templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: {{ hex }};
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes actually I thought about this way but I don't know how to have my html style the background color and keep my css for other elements.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to say. You could use multiple `<link>` tags to include other css files. If you have any code example showing what&how you are trying to achieve, and what part is not working then we would be able to better understand the problem.

Comment: Well, I already attached a css to my html page which will display the color. I don't figure how to conciliate the css and html style:                                              
                                                                                                           `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style2.css?q=1280549770">

<style>
body {
  background-color:white
}
</style>`                                                                                                             It only take the css information and not the html one also.

Comment: Sounds like you are having problem with CSS? Try to update your question or create a new one. Because in this one you asked how to pass a variable into CSS and the answer above seems to give a working solution to your question.

Comment: I figured it out, I just delete the background color information in my css. Many thanks for youR help !